# footer can't put down to the bottom of the website

Tags: html, css

```
#footer-row {
text-align: center;
color: white;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 9pt;
position: absolute;
bottom: 300;
padding-bottom:0;
}

#footer-list {
padding-left: 195px;
padding-right: 25px;
}

#footer-list li {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline;
padding-right: 5px;
}


<div class="row-fluid" id="footer-row">
      <div class="span12">
      <ul id="footer-list">
        <li>&copy; 2013 Foxcode, Inc. All Rights Reserved</li>
        <li> | </li>
        <li>Legal</li>
        <li>Sitemap</li>
        <li>Privacy</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
      </div><!-- ./span12 -->
    </div><!-- ./row-fluid -->
```

I want `#footer-row` goes down to the bottom(background's bottom) , I set some settings in css, but does not work

anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Please update your post to define 'does not work'. What is happening now, and how have you tried to fix it? For best results, create a [jsFiddle] to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues - one is that for the `bottom` property you haven't included a unit, e.g. (px, cm, in, etc) and two you are placing the footer `300` (px I assume you meant) from the bottom of the viewport. If you simply want the footer to stay on the bottom, just specify `bottom: 0;` on `#footer-row`:

http://jsfiddle.net/2nhhE/

Transferring your comment: *"i want the footer goes down to the bottom, not the bottom on the green box*"

You will need to remove `position: relative;` from the `.container-fluid` class and then the footer will show up on the bottom, as that element is establishing a [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#containing-block) for the absolutely positioned footer, making the it relative to the dimensions of `.container-fluid` when you want the footer relative to the viewport.

Here is an example:

http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/8189/testzl.jpg

Comment: hi  http://50.62.140.177/foxcode/index.html#contact could you take a look at my website?

Comment: i want the footer goes down to the bottom, not the bottom on the green box

Comment: Its simple - remove `position: relative;` from `.container-fluid` and then the footer will show up on the bottom, as that element is establishing a containing block, making the footer relative to it. I will attach a screenshot.

Comment: Because you didn't add `bottom: 0;` to `#footer-row` - and make sure to remove `position: relative;` from `.container-fluid`

Comment: so i have to remove position:relative from .container-fluid, then set footer position to relative, then set bottom:0 to footer-row?

Comment: Yes - except set `#footer-row` to **absolute positioning** not relative.

Comment: I did,  but it's still not go down

Comment: `#footer-row` needs **absolute positioning** not relative like you have now - and remember that the text is white so you won't see it.

Comment: and I have other issue, may I still ask you?

Comment: I wrote a jquery,  you can take a look my website,  I want my left side box goes all the way down  , except contact page and homepage

Comment: someone help me to write a jquery

Comment: $('#home-copy').aniAutoHeight(aniHeightSpeed).animate({ backgroundColor: 'white', color: 'gray', paddingTop: 50 }, aniHeightSpeed, function(e) {
   if ($(document).height() > ($('#home-copy').offset().top + $('#home-copy').outerHeight())) {
    $('#home-copy').height($(document).height() - $('#home-copy').offset().top);
   }
  });

Comment: it works to right box,  but  i set $('#home-logo').same copy of above, it does not work for left side

Comment: You're welcome - I'm sure you'll find an answer, just include your code and write your question clearly.

Comment: ok my problem is about making question clear .. I will be improved   thank you